# Make a Button show a new View on click, without using a Segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, segue

I'm working on a multi-page brochure app, and have used segues to join pages. I'm getting to the point where I have 20 or so pages and the segue system seems messy.

I have created a button programmatically in the ViewController. I'm just looking to make that button always links to a different View no matter what page it is on. *This would mean I wouldn't have to draw segues hundreds of times!*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 50, width: 250, height: 75))
    button.backgroundColor = .black
    button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonClicked() {
    print("Button Clicked")
}
```

I can't find any code anywhere that would allow me to do this, so I'm wondering if it's even possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create a custom view, of type UIView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to show another page programmatically without segue.Here is the sample code.

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YoourViewControllerStoryBoardID") as UIViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it.

If you already have the pointer to viewController just present it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do something like this is a PageViewController.
it automatically adds swipe gestures and ... 
there is complete tutorial about it [here](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-steps-to-implement-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift):

some demo:

[image]

Comment: I want to achieve a 'home button' that always links back to the home page. So swipes and other touch gestures aren't much help. I need a button to link to a page. Thank you though, I'll probably use this on future projects!

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's what i understand, you want to switch ViewControllers on button press.

> For the ViewController you want it to Seque too, Add Signupvc to 'Storyboard ID' below Custom Class on the right hand side.

```
@IBAction func differentSequeAction(sender: AnyObject)
 {

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let SignUp: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Signupvc")

    self.present(SignUp, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```